# Error when calling a partial: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've browsed StackOverflow for an answer to my error and haven't had any luck in trying out the solutions to the other questions. I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm doing a to-do list app project. When I'm attempting to view my `todo_list#show` view, I'm getting the following error on line #2:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: todo_items.todo_list_id: SELECT "todo_items".* FROM "todo_items" WHERE "todo_items"."todo_list_id" = ?`

**Show View**

```
<div id="todo_items_wrapper">
   <p><%= render @todo_list.todo_items %></p> #this line is highlighted as the error
<div id="form">
    <%= render "todo_items/form" %>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to call the following partial on line #2; here is the partial file:

```
<%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_list.todo_items.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New Todo" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm assuming I have an issue with my migrations since my error is stating a missing column but I don't have a clue how to iron out this problem. Below is my migration files if needed:

**Migration Files**

```
class CreateTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_lists do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**and...**

```
class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_items do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.references :todo_lists, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160203002224) do

  create_table "todo_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "todo_lists_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "todo_items", ["todo_lists_id"], name: "index_todo_items_on_todo_lists_id"

  create_table "todo_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end
```

Let me know if any other files are needed to help with the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is due to the wrong name in migration file (todo_lists, where it should be todo_list)

```
 t.references :todo_lists, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

should be

```
 t.references :todo_list, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

you can write a migration to rename the column name to fix it.